# Problem running the LinearRegression algorithm on the weka "Problem in classifier evaluation: Null

Tags: weka, data-mining

I'm working on an article using weka and after trying to use the LinearRegression algorithm it always returns the "Problem evaluating classifier: null". The arff file is correct, I already ran some other algorithms and there was no problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc51h.jpg)

What appears on the console after the error is this, which I honestly could not decipher what the real problem is.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv4BC.jpg)

The file has more than 600k lines, but here a small part (in Portuguese, I am Brazilian ¯_(ツ)_/¯)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EHE7.jpg)

Comment: Can you post all/part of your arff file here (e.g. the whole header plus some of the cases)?  Then I'll try to take a look at it.

Comment: i added a image with a small part

Comment: Thanks, but I can't figure it out. I created a similar data set (even included one missing data (?) in the Deco attribute), and mine runs without any problem.  I'm using 3.9 rather than 3.8 Weka, but that's unlikely to be the problem.